# XML list serialization

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following XML:

```
<Product>
    <Categories>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Id>8</Id>
    </Categories>
</Product>
```

I'm deserializing it to the .NET type using `XmlSerializer`.
My goal is to have it deserealized as:

```
public class Product
{
    public List<int> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't manage to deserealize it to such type (the `Categories` property is empty). Any ideas how can I do it?

I managed to do it with, but I'm not happy with such solution.

```
[Serializable]
public class Categories
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Int32> Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I know, I can do it with Linq to XML, but I wonder if I can do it with `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes:

```
public class Product
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem("Id")]
    public List<int> Categories { get; set; }
}
```